# "to document in categories the items included in the deposit transaction" -- I don't quite understand

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposit_slip)

> A deposit slip is a form supplied by a bank for a depositor to fill out **to document in categories the items included in the deposit transaction**.

[image]

**to document in** - is this a phrasal verb? I also don't quite get how **categories** and **the items** fit together.

Comment: In categories:  there are usually only two categories referenced on the slip: "cash" and "checks". One would normally say "by category".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A deposit slip is a form supplied by a bank for a depositor to fill out **to document in categories the items included in the deposit transaction**.

This sentence is interesting because it is arranged in a special way. It uses *heavy noun phrase shift*. When a noun, usually a direct object, is very, very long, we can move it past any other phrases and put it at the end of the sentence. Here the direct object is:

- the items included in the deposit transaction.

This is a very long noun phrase. If it was short we would put it straight after the verb:

- to document the items included in the deposit transaction  in categories.

Because the noun phrase is very long it is a bit difficult to understand this clause. The noun phrase here is complicated. We can make it easier to understand if we just use the head noun in the noun phrase. This is the word *items*:

- to document the items in categories.

This just means that when they record the items they put them in categories. For example, they show how much money was in cheques, how much money was in £10 notes, how much money was in £5 notes and so forth. Here *in categories* is a preposition phrase showing 'where' they record the items.

The whole sentence is quite complicated because it uses several infinitives of purpose and relative clauses. We can put the meaning together like this:

- A deposit slip is a form

What kind of form?

- A deposit slip is a form supplied by the bank.

Supplied by the bank for what?

- supplied by the bank for a depositor to fill out [= to complete]

Why do they fill it out?

- to document the items in categories

What items?

- the items which are included in the deposit transaction.

This means the items they are paying into the bank.

[Here are lots of pictures of deposit slips!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=deposit+slip&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-SearchBox&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=XzV-VIjuNojtatqxgsAN&ved=0CAUQ_AU)

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 5):

**To document in** is not a phrasal verb. What is happening is that **in categories** is being used as a prepositional phrase. You could remove it and say,

> to document the items included in the deposit transaction

**In categories** is being added to specify how the items are being documented.